# Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param() [mysqli-stmt.bind-param]: Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepare

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I don't know why I'm getting this error I think I have enough defined parameters?! any help?

```
if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO members (username, email, password, salt, privilegio) VALUES ('".$username."','".$email."','".$password."','".$salt."','".$privilegio."')")) {    
   $insert_stmt->bind_param('sssss', $username, $email, $password, $random_salt, $privilegio); 
   // Execute the prepared query.
   $insert_stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: Please open the documentation about function you use and compare with your code. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: IMHO OP should rather read http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php and in general http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should be

```
if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO members (username, email, password, salt, privilegio) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)") {    
   $insert_stmt->bind_param('sssss', $username, $email, $password, $random_salt, $privilegio); 
   // Execute the prepared query.
   $insert_stmt->execute();
}
```